# How can I show a paragraph with lines without <br>

Tags: html, css

I have a text, I want to show it with lines

Like this without `<br>` tag.

Example:

```
hello.
how are you ?
fine !
```

Not like this :

```
hello. how are you ? fine !
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to achieve line breaks without using the <br/> tag? Did you try <br/> and it didn't work for you?  Can you give a little background?

Comment: You should be using separate paragraphs for this. A conversation (such as you have there) is a series of ***separate*** statements...and should be broken up as such.

Comment: <br> tag works but .. I want do it without this tag .. I got a text in my database but when I show it I get a small problem that all the text comes in the same line

Comment: One of the benefits to doing it another way is less characters. This results in a lower file size. Creating separate paragraphs is probably far less efficient then using preformatted text

Comment: If you are going to use separate paragraphs, then you should write someting like: `<p>Hello.</p><p>How are you?</p>` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `pre` tag. One of the benefits of this over the `br` tag, is that it's fewer characters to write. With `br`, you'd have to use about five of them. This can result in a larger file size. Although this difference is small, it is a minor improvement.

> The HTML `pre` element defines preformatted text.
>
> The text inside a pre element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and **line breaks**:

You can keep the original styles by using the `style` attribute. Depending on what font-size and font-family you want, you can do something like this.

```html
<pre style="font-size: 16px, font-family: Verdana" >hello.
how are you ?
fine !
not like this :
hello. how are you ? fine !
someone can help me ?</pre>
```

Comment: I got a problem (i.imgur.com/pI1ADFa.png) .. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Sorry !!.. I am marking it like answered thank you again .. and sorry guys it's my first time ask a question on stackoverflow